# Haskell functor for red-black tree

Tags: haskell, functor, red-black-tree

So I'm learning Haskell and I have a red-black tree with different types in red and black nodes implemented like this:

```
data Rbtree a1 b1 = EmptyTree | Node a1 (Rbtree b1 a1) (Rbtree b1 a1) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

And now I need to define a functor instance for it. Because `Rbtree` is a type constructor that takes two parameters I have to make an instance for `Rbtree c`. And after this I'm  stuck. My code now is something like this:

```
instance Functor (Rbtree c) where
fmap f EmptyTree = EmptyTree
fmap f (Node x left right) = Node x (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

As you could guess that does't compile. ([compilation errors](http://puu.sh/8N48e.png)). I understand that `fmap` for it has to be `(a -> b) -> (Rbtree c) a -> (Rbtree c) b` and looking deeper for `Node` part it has to be `(a -> b) -> (Node c (Rbtree a c) (Rbree a c)) -> (Node c (Rbtree b c) (Rbree b c))`. What I do not understand is how to unfold `left` and `right` so i can apply `f` only to part of it. I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: take a look at `Bifunctor`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html

Comment: Also, your `data` definition of red-black tree does not use `b1` — you actually have only `a1` nodes.

Comment: @CrazyFIZRUK: Note how the child-nodes have the type arguments flipped, which is causing the problem.

Comment: @Xeo right, missed that part.

Comment: What about using GADTs to ensure all Red-Black tree invariants in the types? :) I don't think it would be too much hassle.

Comment: @uraf The only invariant you need to ensure (considering `EmptyTree` black) is that every path contains the same number of black nodes (correct me if I'm wrong). But you would need type-level numbers to ensure that, right? Then you would need dependent sum (Σ-type) to define `insert` (since sometimes it increases that associated number and sometimes not). So I guess GADTs can't help here.

Comment: @uraf oh, you can actually hide associated number behind existential like this: `data MyRBTree a = forall n. MyRBTree (RBTree n a)` and define `insert` over `MyRBTree` simulating Σ-type, like here: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ti5il/redblack_trees_in_haskell_using_gadts_existential/

Comment: @CrazyFIZRUK, yeah I meant exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
instance Functor (Rbtree c) where
  fmap = fmap_even where
     fmap_even _ EmptyTree = EmptyTree
     fmap_even f (Node x left right) = Node x (fmap_odd f left) (fmap_odd f right)
     fmap_odd  _ EmptyTree = EmptyTree
     fmap_odd  f (Node x left right) = Node (f x) (fmap_even f left) (fmap_even f right)
```

Your definition of RB tree doesn't make much sense to me, but in case i'm missing something, here's a Functor instance that is compatible with it.

Comment: "'fmap_even' is not a (visible) method of class 'Functor'".
Same with 'fmap_odd'. Is it really possible to define methods in instances like this? Though it looks like a correct idea to me.

Comment: @Genmilhas do you get this error for `Functor` instance or are you trying to call `fmap_even` outside of this `instance` definition?

Comment: @Crazy FIZRUK I get it from functor instance.

Comment: @Genmilhas Looks like an indentation error to me. Are `fmap` and `fmap_even` indented the same in your copy? They shouldn't be.

Answer (score 8):

You can make your `Rbtree` a `Bifunctor` (see [`bifunctors` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors)) like this:

```
import Data.Bifunctor

data Rbtree a1 b1 = EmptyTree | Node a1 (Rbtree b1 a1) (Rbtree b1 a1)

instance Bifunctor Rbtree where
  bimap _ _ EmptyTree = EmptyTree
  bimap f g (Node x l r) = Node (f x) (bimap g f l) (bimap g f r)
```

With this instance you now have both `first` and `second` functions to map over red or black nodes (`second` ~ `fmap`). Actually you can define `Functor` instance like this:

```
instance Functor (Rbtree c) where
  fmap = second
```

---

#### Example

```
>>> let t = Node 1 (Node "hello" EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree
>>> bimap show length t
Node "1" (Node 5 EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree
>>> fmap length t
Node 1 (Node 5 EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree
>>> first show t
Node "1" (Node "hello" EmptyTree EmptyTree) EmptyTree
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enforce all [Red-Black tree invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties) using [GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADTs_for_dummies) and some type hackery ([existential quantification](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type), [type arithmetic](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_arithmetic), [data kinds](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html)). The properties are:

1. A node is either red or black.
2. The root is black.
3. All leaves (NIL) are black.
4. Every red node must have two black child nodes.
5. Every path from a given node to any of its descendant
   leaves contains the same number of black nodes.

And here is example code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving, ExistentialQuantification,
             KindSignatures, DataKinds #-}

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
data Color = Red | Black

data Node :: Color -> Nat -> * -> * where
    Nil :: Node Black Zero a
    RedNode :: a -> Node Black n a -> Node Black n a -> Node Red n a
    BlackNode :: a -> Node c1 n a -> Node c2 n a -> Node Black (Succ n) a

data RBTree a = forall n. RBTree (Node Black n a)

deriving instance (Show a) => Show (Node c n a)
deriving instance (Show a) => Show (RBTree a)

instance Functor (Node c n) where
    fmap f Nil = Nil
    fmap f (RedNode   x l r) = RedNode   (f x) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)
    fmap f (BlackNode x l r) = BlackNode (f x) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)

instance Functor RBTree where
    fmap f (RBTree t) = RBTree (fmap f t)
```

You can use it like this:

```
tree = RBTree $ BlackNode 3 (RedNode 4 Nil Nil) (RedNode 5 Nil Nil)
main = print $ fmap (*5) tree
```

Result:

```
RBTree (BlackNode 15 (RedNode 20 Nil Nil) (RedNode 25 Nil Nil))
```

But this won't compile:

```
tree = RBTree $ BlackNode 3 (RedNode 4 Nil Nil) (BlackNode 5 Nil Nil)
```

You will get a *nice* error message:

```
Couldn't match type `Succ Zero' with `Zero'
Expected type: Node Black Zero a0
  Actual type: Node Black (Succ Zero) a0
In the return type of a call of `BlackNode'
In the third argument of `BlackNode', namely
  `(BlackNode 5 Nil Nil)'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `BlackNode 3 (RedNode 4 Nil Nil) (BlackNode 5 Nil Nil)'
```

Comment: You can make this scheme a little swanker if you throw in `DataKinds`; see the module in the ghc testsuite https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/testsuite/tests/polykinds/RedBlack.hs

Comment: @Arthur, thanks for suggestion. As I am rather inexperienced Haskell programmer, I wasn't aware that something like `DataKinds` existed. :)